# Floating image with text; CSS not applied

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build my web application and am using bootstrap template. In one of the pages I had to provide an inline image with the text, with the image supposed to float left and text towards right.

The paragraph element in the html was part of a div. I looked up and found links which suggested to add an img property to the CSS rule of the parent div. This is the div in which I was trying to add the image

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <p style='float:right;' > <img src={{ url_for('static',filename='img/ankulGupta.tiff') }}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius praesentium recusandae illo eaque architecto error, repellendus iusto reprehenderit, doloribus, minus sunt. Numquam at quae voluptatum in officia voluptas voluptatibus, minus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added the float rule like this

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row>img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

But despite all this I was unable to apply these rules to the image. After much trying I just plainly added the style rules in the img tag itself to get the job done.

```
<img style='float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-top:8.5px; width: 210px; height:194px' src={{ url_for('static',filename='img/img.jpg') }}>
```

Could you please explain what was the issue? Maybe I didn't add the img CSS rule under the right parent CSS rule. I am new to this so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the code `row>img`. In CSS, the symbol `>` looks for the direct children from the parent. As per your code `img` is not the direct children. It is a grand children. So change your code

```
 .row>img{
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
 }
```

to

```
.row img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment below, you mentioned this is not working. Yes, you have to apply all the remaining styles here as you have added inline img tag like below.

```
.row img{
   margin-right:10px; margin-top:8.5px; width: 210px; height:194px;
   float: left;
 }
```

**Code Snippet**

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row img{
  margin-right:10px; margin-top:8.5px; width: 210px; height:194px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <p style='float:right;' > <img src='img/ankulGupta.tiff'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius praesentium recusandae illo eaque architecto error, repellendus iusto reprehenderit, doloribus, minus sunt. Numquam at quae voluptatum in officia voluptas voluptatibus, minus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was actually the first thing I had tried but even this didn't work. This is the most commonly suggested solution over internet but somehow it is not working and I am unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.row>img` selector will work only if `img` is present as a immediate child of `row` container in DOM tree structure. To fix this you should make generic approach like following:

```
.row img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Or it if you want more specific then you should apply a `class` selector on images.

```
.image-style {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

<img class="image-style" src={{ url_for('static',filename='img/img.jpg') }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the CSS applied to the image correctly, change your CSS rule to this:

```
.row > div > p > img {                                                          
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

You rule isn't working because the `img` tag isn't the direct child of the `.row` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row>img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Change To This

```
.row img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

I hope it will help you.